# Two questions for MS SQL CE - commercial use and remote access

Tags: windows, sql-server, licensing

I am sorry but I was unable to find the answers. I know SQL CE is free. But is it free for commercial applications? Or is it free for commerical services that are not sold but are used for profit?

And the second question - I know it's usually a local db, but what if I wanted to connect from a different location to SQL CE, is it still possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Compact is a single user embedded database engine. It only allows connections from the same Windows session (could be different processes). It is free for all types of applications, but if you connect to SQL Server, a CAL is required.